# How to save image on Server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save selected image on server images folder

like http://url/public_html/images/

HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<button type="button" id="btnInsertAuto"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Javascript

```
$('#btnInsertAuto').on('click', function () {
  var  Name = $('#Name1').val();
  var Note = $('#Note2').val();
  var image=$('#files').val();;

  document.getElementById("Name1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Note2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("files").files[0].name

  insertAutoKey(Name, Note, image);

});
```

Comment: use ajax to send it to server.

Comment: why did you used java tag ?

Comment: Obviously, you need some server side component to handle the image upload.

Comment: i am new in java script so i have no idea so please send mi example

Comment: Please use the search function in the upper righthand corner of the site. There are many questions about exactly this. Also you can use your preferred web search engine to find gazillions of examples.